# how to force the children method arguments to extend specific class for multiple methods in java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, design-patterns

I have an interface:

```
public interface Parent{
  Integer method1(Payment payment);
  Integer method2(Invoice invoice, Payment payment);
}
```

And I have multiple kinds of classes that `extends` Payment and Invoice class, let's say `PaymentType1`, `InvoiceType1` and `PaymentType2`, `InvoiceType2` are my children classes of `Payment` and `Invoice`.

Now, I want to create two classes that extend `Parent` in a way to force child classes to just use the extended class of `Payment` and `Invoice`. For example something like this:

First:

```
public class ChildType1 extends Parent{
  public Integer method1(PaymentType1 payment){...}
  public Integer method2(InvoiceType1 invoice, PaymentType1 payment){...}
}
```

Second:

```
public class Child2 extends Parent{
  public Integer method1(PaymentType2 payment){...}
  public Integer method2(InvoiceType2 invoice, PaymentType2 payment){...}
}
```

what kinds of solutions can I use to resolve it?

Comment: You could use generics: `public interface Parent<P extends Payment, I extends Invoice> { Integer method1(P payment); Integer method2(I invoice, P payment); }`, then you can have your two children: `public class ChildType1 implements Parent<PaymentType1, InvoiceType1> {` and `public class ChildType2 implements Parent<PaymentType2, InvoiceType2> {`

Comment: Actually I had this solution, but the problem was the number of this generic types, because I have more than 5 classes in my interface methods arguments.
Do you think I can fix it using bound method generics or not?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an *XY-problem*.

You've designed your classes in such a way that you can't benefit from Polymorphism and instead using `Payment` and `Invoice` types you need to discriminate between their subtypes (like `PaymentType1`, `PaymentType2`).

And that impedes implementing the contract of the `Parent` interface. Attempts of loosening the constraints of the contract would not solve the actual the problem caused by the design flow.

The contract defined by `Parent` is fine.

The problem is rooted on the level of subclasses `PaymentType1`/`PaymentType2` and `InvoiceType1`/`InvoiceType2` which doesn't respect the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) because you're unable to use them in place of `Payment` and `Invoice`.

> Functions that use pointers or references to base classes must be able to **use objects of derived classes without knowing it**.

That where you can find the room for improvement.